# Check if App is in Review or Live on App Store programatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change app domain if app is in review to avoid some breaking functionalities,is there any way i can know it?

Comment: Are you talking about the "associated website" domain for universal links? That cannot be changed dynamically/at runtime, as it's baked into the app's entitlement file.

Comment: No i need to change my backend API to test server.

Comment: @KhushbuJudal I have found a way to easily check if an app is in Review. I used this method to allow crypto transactions on my app without giving Apple a cut. Are you still interested?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do -—if your app is set to "Manual Release"—- is to make your change once you click **Release this app** (or when you see the app has been approved).

Another, more automated way; you might have a look at the [App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/), that's your best bet.
If you for example take a look at '[Read App Information](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/read_app_information)', there is a lot of information available there.

It's up to you to check where your information is listed (and how to get it). i'm guessing `fields[appStoreVersions]` might be a good place to start, specifically the fields `appStoreState`, `appStoreReviewDetail`, etc.

On a side note: if there are breaking functionalities in your app, you should not only avoid this from reaching the Apple Review Team, but also your users in general.

Also, you might risk being removed from the Apple Developer Program with these practices. From the [Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> **2.3.1** Don’t include any hidden, dormant, or undocumented features in your app; your app’s functionality should be clear to end users and
> App Review. All new features, functionality, and product changes must
> be described with specificity in the Notes for Review section of App
> Store Connect (generic descriptions will be rejected) and accessible
> for review. Similarly, you should not market your app on the App Store
> or offline as including content or services that it does not actually
> offer (e.g. iOS-based virus and malware scanners). Egregious or
> repeated behavior is grounds for removal from the Developer Program.
> We work hard to make the App Store a trustworthy ecosystem and expect
> our app developers to follow suit; if you’re dishonest, we don’t want
> to do business with you.

Comment: You're referring to `2.3.1 Don’t include any hidden, dormant, or undocumented features in your app; your app’s functionality should be clear to end users and App Review.`, afaict.

Comment: You're right! I updated my answer.